# Inter-vlan routing with unmanaged switch?

Tags: routing, switch, router, vlan, interface

[image]I have a Cisco 3650 with inter-vlan routing enabled. All vlans reach each other with no problems. The problem appeared when I connected an unmanaged switch to an interface on the cisco. I set up a vlan with the same ip range of the unmanaged switch, I also set up an interface vlan in the same ip range of the unmanaged switch. Now, when i'm on the exec mode on the cisco switch, i can reach all devices on the unmanaged switch, however, from any other valn, I cannot.

```
no aaa new-model
system mtu routing 1500
vtp domain h873.eur.nsroot.net
vtp mode transparent
ip subnet-zero
ip routing
vlan 116
 name PROD_VLAN_111
!
vlan 120,200
!
vlan 211
 name MGMT_PHY_211
!
vlan 212
 name MGMT_APP_212
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 211
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2  
 switchport access vlan 212
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 116
 switchport mode access
!

interface GigabitEthernet0/11
 description Connection to Unmanaged Switch
 switchport access vlan 200
 switchport mode access
!

interface GigabitEthernet0/14
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/16
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/18
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/20
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/22
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/24
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk

interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan116
 ip address 172.16.116.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan120
 ip address 10.11.120.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan200
ip address 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan211
 ip address 10.11.211.1 255.255.255.0
 !
  interface Vlan212
  ip address 10.11.212.1 255.255.255.0
 !
 router ospf 100
  log-adjacency-changes
  redistribute connected subnets
  network 172.16.116.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 !
  ip default-gateway 192.168.1.165
  ip classless
 ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
 ip http server
 ip http secure-server
 !
```

So for example, if i run "ping 192.168.1.100 source 10.11.211.1" the pings are fine, but if i run "ping 192.168.1.1 source 10.11.211.1"
it is not successful. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Switch#ping 192.168.1.1
 Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
 !!!!!
 Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/8 ms 

Switch#ping 192.168.1.1 source 10.11.211.1 Type escape sequence to abort.
 Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
 Packet sent with a source address of 10.11.211.1
 .....
 Success rate is 0 percent (0/5) 

Switch#ping 192.168.1.100 source 10.11.211.1
 Packet sent with a source address of 10.11.211.1
 !!!!!
 Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/9 ms
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the switch configuration.

Comment: To which interface is the unmanaged switch connected?

Comment: interface gig 0/11

Comment: The `description` command is your friend. You should use it.

Comment: Do your devices on the unmanaged switch have their default gateway set to 192.168.1.100?

Comment: I should use it more often, you are right...but what about the main problem here, do you need any output from the switch?

Comment: no, they have their default gateway set to 192.168.1.1, which is the isp router (it is connected to the unmanaged switch).

Comment: The `default-gateway` command should _not_ be used on a switch that is routing. You seem to be using OSPF to connect to other routers, and you have defined a default route. This is really not something you should do. If this switch is routing, then it should be the gateway for the connected hosts.

Comment: The default gateway for a host should be the SVI address on the switch for the VLAN to which the host is connected.

Comment: Yes, I just removed it, it was not supposed to be here, and the OSPF is used only to route with the NSX Edge I'm not using OSPF in any other part of the network.

Comment: It is, but the problem is that even if i'm on the switch I cannot ping any device on the unmanaged switch using any source address of any SVI that I created on the switch

Comment: You just wrote that the gateway for the hosts is `192.168.1.1`. That will not work for any host not on that network. A gateway is the host on a network that knows how to reach other networks. In this case, it is the switch, and hosts on the `192.168.1.0/24` network should have their gateway set to `192.168.1.100`, the switch SVI.

Comment: Hosts on the other networks (VLANs) should have their gateways set to the SVI address of the corresponding VLAN.

Comment: The gateway for each host on each vlan is it's SVI not the 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Switch#ping 192.168.1.1


Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/8 ms
Switch#ping 192.168.1.1 source 10.11.211.1

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of 10.11.211.1
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
Switch#ping 192.168.1.100 source 10.11.211.1


Packet sent with a source address of 10.11.211.1
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/9 ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hosts on the unmanaged switch have a gateway set to `192.168.1.1`, then traffic from those hosts to a different network will be sent to that router, and if that router needs to send back to the switch on that network, it will not. Routers have split-horizon, meaning that they will not route back to the same network on which a packet is received.

You want the inter-VLAN routing to happen on the switch, not the WAN router, so the switch must be the gateway for all the hosts. The WAN router should inject the default route into OSPF, and you should not have a default route on the switch.

Comment: Then, I don't understand how the below ping is working from the switch:

Comment: Switch#ping 192.168.1.1
     Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
     !!!!!
     Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/8 ms

Comment: Because the source of your pings is on the same network as your devices, so no routing is required.

Comment: So basically, I need to change the topology so that the WAN router is connected directly to cisco switch?

Comment: @absalah, you need to understand that frames are sent directly at layer-2, and packets sent to a different network are frames with the configured gateway address. You can ping anything on the same network because the frames are sent directly to the desintation host, but pinging to a different network, the packets are frames and sent directly to the configured gateway, then the gateway will strip the frame and add a frame for the the next network. A router will not route from a network back to the same network.

Comment: @absalah, the WAN router simply needs to inject the default route into OSPF, and all the OSPF routers will then have the default route from OSPF. You really don't need to change the topology, just make sure that all the hosts have the correct gateway, and that the default route is in the routing table.

Comment: I am not using OSPF for all my environment, I am only using OSPF for the vmware NSX EDGE.

Comment: The unmanaged switch is what we have been using all along, the ISP router (the gateway 192.168.1.1) have been connected there to begin with. Then I connected the cisco switch because I have three servers that need to connect to the internet. I can't simply change the default gateway of all the devices that are connected to the unmanaged switch, and also, OSPF is insignificant here because it is only used with the servers, not the whole environment, the environment is working without OSPF.

Comment: Is the NSX EDGE the WAN router? You are unclear. In any case, the gateways of the hosts on the VLANs needs to be the switch. You could have the inter-VLAN routing happen on the `192.168.1.1` router, but you would need to trunk to the router and have subinterfaces for each VLAN on that router. What is happening is that hosts on the `192.168.1.0/24` network will send all traffic for other networks to the router instead of the switch. The router cannot then send the traffic back out the same network to the switch because of split-horizon.

Answer (score 3):

The hosts on the unmanaged switch subnet need their default routes to point at the gateway you've created on the 3650.  The hosts already routing through the 3650 can likely reach the new subnet but the new subnet's hosts need to understand to how to send traffic in return.  I'd suggest that VLAN200 on the 3650 should potentially just assume the IP of the present default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

It's not. Feasible at all to do inter-Vlan routing by deploying unmanaged switch inline . Unmanaged switch is not capable to create and modify and delete Vlans . So it's not feasible.

To accomplish your requirement deploy managed switch and further connect end host to managed switch allowing specific Vlan .